# How to check if clients connect to IMAP/POP via TLS or SSL?

Tags: ssl, dovecot, imap, tls, pop3

I am willing to disable SSL on my dovecot servers (Debian GNU/Linux), leaving TLS as the only option.
Before doing so, I would like to know who is still connecting via SSL with older or misconfigured clients, so to warn them and assist the migration to a TLS capable application.
Is there a way to tell from the server logs (or any other means) who is still using SSL?

Comment: Did you mean connect via STARTTLS instead TLS? Or did you mean how to log client who using SSL(v3) and using TLS1, TLS1.1, TLS1,2?

Comment: I need to identify and isolate connections like: SSLv2, SSLv3, STARTTLS+SSL from TLS or STARTTLS+TLS…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `verbose_ssl = yes`. This will make Dovecot log all the problems it sees with SSL connections.